# Event Loop and EventEmitter in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, event-loop

I have written some basic Nodejs code in which has

1. a recursive function `myFunction` with `process.nextTick()`
2. a long running for loop

Both blocks are emitting events, The code is as follows

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter = new EventEmitter();
var counter = 1;

emitter.on('message',
    (message)=>
        {
            console.log('Hey I have got this message ' +message);
        }
    );

emitter.on('syncMsg',
    (message)=>
        {
            console.log('voila the sync message is  ' +message);
        }
    );

function myFunction(){
    process.nextTick(
    ()=>
    {
        emitter.emit('message','message'+counter);
        counter++;
        myFunction();
    }
    )
}

myFunction();

for(var i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    emitter.emit('syncMsg','syncMsg'+counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Now while executing the file, the listener for `syncMsg` event gets triggered synchronously before even a single event being emitted for `message` event. Why is the execution behaving synchronously?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling your function asynchronously. You need to do that using a callback on the event you want it to fire on just like you did for the lamda functions you console.log the message

Answer (score 0):

The `message` event is only going to be emitted on the next tick of the event loop, which happens some time *after* your `for` loop (which emits events immediately) completes and there is nothing left to do on the current tick.

Comment: I agree that the emit events within the for loop would be triggered immediately. However my concern was related to the event listeners of 'syncMsg' event, why are they getting invoked synchronously before the next tick?

Comment: Because `emit()` always calls all event handlers for the emitted event immediately (in the order in which they were added)?